# Listar registos diários?

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

O meu programa faz a inserção de registos quer dos serviços quer dos computadores de uma biblioteca escolar. Como tal a secretaria da biblioteca tem de fazer um registo diário e eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma listagem apenas das requisições(serviços ou computadores) diárias?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo era eu através da textbox com a hora do sistema poder listar todas as requisições feitas no proprio dia, quer fosse em ListView ou DataGrid, no entanto o codigo que eu tenho lista todas requisições feitas na BD.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O forma de fazer a inserção das requisições é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código do botao "guardar"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você está populando a DataGrid?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro populando?

Comment: Como esta a preencher os dados da DataGrid quando clicado em Guardar?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro editei, está em cima. Faz a inserção no registo de serviços e depois na listagem é suposto que apareça só os registos efetuados num tal dia.

Comment: Digo, quando você clica em `Guardar` como você busca os dados? É por `SqlCommand` ?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro é sim

Comment: Pode colocar o código na sua pergunta pra facilitar a resolução?

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem como o horário informado vai afetar a consulta se você quer listar todos do dia, mas pra isso você pode alterar seu `sql` para `SELECT * FROM Requisição WHERE dataRequisicao >= Convert(date, getdate())`

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Eu já tinha tentado o select com um `Where` mas não com `Convert(date, getdate())`
Utilizei o seu select e tenho o que queria, obrigado!

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Com o código que eu e o meu colega temos, depois de clicar no botão guardar fica tudo como nós queremos, mas quando saímos e voltamos a entrar na aplicação, os dados guardados desaparecem. Há alguma forma de os manter? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seu SQL correto seja esse aqui:

```
SELECT Requisição.dataRequisicao, 
       Requisição.codRequisicao, 
       Utilizadores.numProcesso, 
       Utilizadores.nomeUtilizador, 
       Turma.Ano, 
       Turma.Turma, 
       Turma.Curso 
FROM Requisição 
INNER JOIN TipoServiço ON Requisição.codTpServico = TipoServiço.codTpServico
INNER JOIN Utilizadores ON Requisição.numProcesso = Utilizadores.numProcesso
INNER JOIN TpUtilizador ON Utilizadores.CodUtilizador = TpUtilizador.CodUtilizador 
INNER JOIN Turma ON Utilizadores.codTurma = Turma.codTurma 
WHERE (Convert(date, Requisição.dataRequisicao) = Convert(date, getdate()))
```

O que você postou nos comentários está com vários erros de sintaxe, faltando `=` e com `()` a mais, então aconselho testar antes no SqlServer.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente este suposto comando de "guardar" ou tecnicamente conhecido como inserção está confuso pelo fato de seu comando ser uma uma seleção "Select * from...." somente esta populando o grid na unha ?
quanto a listagem, para conseguir listar todas seus registros de acordo com a data atual basta incluir uma clausula where ..

```
"Select * from requisicao where(dataRequisicao = getDate())"
```

(obs: Por boas praticas de programação não se aconselha dar nomes a tabelas,procedures,views,e etc com acentuação)

Comment: Jeferson, posso estar enganado, mas esse `SELECT` tem problema com horários não?

Comment: Problemas com horário?se refere ao fato do valor retornado pelo metodo ´`getDate()` não estar no mesmo formato com o salvo nos registros?

Comment: Exatamente, pelo fato da dataRequisicao ser DATETIME acredito que influencia nesse `=`, não?

Comment: Não , pois o valor retornado pelo método é do tipo datetime, único cuidado a ser tomado e pra ver o idioma atual,pois o retorno traz a data em formato de acordo com o mesmo.

Comment: Por isso o problema, o método retorna hora atual e ele quer qualquer hora do dia de hoje.

Comment: O método retorna tanto hora como data atual

Comment: Sim, mas seu `SELECT` vai fazer algo do tipo `WHERE ('11/06/2015 14:38:49' = '11/06/2015 15:27:32')` e não vai retornar :)

Comment: Ah sim , como eu disse é preciso ver o formato de ambas datas , porem isso é um  fácil  ajuste :)

Comment: Igual eu falei nos comentários da pergunta, eu recomendo fazer cast pra transformar a `dataRequisicao` em date e com operador ">=". [Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/789/0)

Comment: Sim , porém o operador de ">" se torna meio que inútil já que nunca vai existir um registro com uma data maior que a atual não é mesmo ? rs

Comment: eu tentei usar o seguinte select com inner join e dá 1 erro:
`"SELECT Requisição.dataRequisicao, Requisição.codRequisicao, Utilizadores.numProcesso, Utilizadores.nomeUtilizador, Turma.Ano, Turma.Turma, Turma.Curso"

"FROM Requisição INNER JOIN"
"TipoServiço ON Requisição.codTpServico TipoServiço.codTpServico INNER JOIN"
"Utilizadores ON Requisição.numProcesso Utilizadores.numProcesso INNER JOIN"
"TpUtilizador ON Utilizadores.CodUtilizador TpUtilizador.CodUtilizador INNER JOIN"
"Turma ON Utilizadores.codTurma = Turma.codTurma"
"WHERE(Requisição.dataRequisicao >= Convert(Of Date, GETDATE())())"`

Comment: @MaiconCarraro quando uso o seu select sozinho dá bem quando tento fazer o inner join para obter dados na datagrid de outras tabelas aparece um erro